# How to have a pointer to class A OR class B in my class?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I've created a C++ class that has a public member that is a pointer to an unrelated class. Here it is:

```
class ADS_1x15 : public Sensors {
 public:
  ADS_1x15(uint8_t addr = 0x48, adsGain_t gain = GAIN_TWOTHIRDS, String = "");
  Adafruit_ADS1115* ads;

};
```

It's the base class for some other classes that do different things with the Adafruit ADS1115 ADC, so the member `ads` is used in any descendent class.

There is a very similar Adafruit ADC called an ADS1015, and I'd like for my classes to work with either of the two ADC's. Of course, an Adafruit_ADS1015 is a very different object than an Adafruit_ADS1115. In my base class, I want to be able to pass in a parameter that tells the class "include a pointer to EITHER an Adafruit_ADS1015 OR an Adafruit_ADS1115, but whichever one is used, make the variable name for the pointer be the same: `ads`". All the methods for the two objects are identical, so once I get `ads` pointed to the correct object, everything in my classes will work, regardless of which ADS is used.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do `Adafruit_ADS1015` and `Adafruit_ADS1115` share a common base class?

Comment: If they share a base class you can use a single pointer. If they don't, consider a `union`, or two pointers for clarity.

Comment: @tadman I'd prefer `std::variant` over a `union` almost every time.

Comment: @aschepler If available (C++17), yeah, that too!

Comment: You can make `ADS_1x15` be a templated class, where the type of `ads` is specified in a template parameter.  Then the user of `ADS_1x15` can decide which type to use.  Otherwise, like you said, since `Adafruit_ADS1015` and `Adafruit_ADS1115` have the same methods then polymorphism is a good choice for this situation, make them derive from a common base class and then make `ads` be a pointer of that type.

Comment: The base class is `Adafruit_ADS1015` - it inherits from nothing. `Adafruit_ADS1115` inherits from `Adafruit_ADS1015`, with only one parameter - the address. There are no methods that are specific to the `Adafruit_ADS1115', although there are a few data members that are different (something called the `m_conversionDelay` and the `m_bitShift`), which are set by the 1115's constructor. 

I didn't realize this before I posted my question. Does that change your suggestions?

Comment: It seems like making `ADS_1x15` be a templated class might be the answer, but I don't know how to implement that. Can someone illustrate it in a few lines of code, or do I need to do a deep dive on template classes? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried to make it a templated class, but now I can't format my code to show you what I did. (Not "{code}" button anywhere on the screen I'm working on right now.) But here's what I did: immediately before the line `class ADS_1x15 : public Sensors {` , I added `template <class T>`.

Then I replaced the line `Adafruit_ADS1115* ads;` with `<T>* ads;`.

The compiler complained about "error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token", referring to the one on the line `<T>* ads;`.

Before I start sprinkling "<T>" all over the place - what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How to have a pointer to class A OR class B in my class?
>
> Is this possible?

Yes. It is possible. You are describing dynamic polymorphism. If `Adafruit_ADS1115` and `Adafruit_ADS1015` share a base class `B`, then `B*` can point to (base sub object of) either child class.

There is also another form of dynamic polymorphism which doesn't require inheritance: Type erasure. There is unconstrained type erasure that can be achieved with `std::any`, which allows your class to contain objects of any type. And there is constrained type erasure that allows a finite set of types that can be achieved with a tagged union (`std::variant`). There are also specialised type-erasure wrappers for particular use cases such as `std::function` for storing any type of callable.

---

Note that dynamic polymorphism typically involves some amount of overhead which might not be necessary in your case.

An alternative is static polymorphism that can be achieved through the use of templates. In this case for example, you might define a following template:

```
template<class Adafruit_ADS1x15>
struct ADS_1x15 : Sensors {
    Adafruit_ADS1x15* ads;
```

Comment: Plus, if the existing classes don't have a useful common interface class and can't be modified, but you create an abstract interface class that mimics them, and a template class which inherits the new abstract interface and implements them by redirecting to the parameterized concrete class, then you have implemented your own custom type erasure!

Comment: @eerorika, that seems like maybe the way to go (the template approach), but I don't understand how the user of MY class will pass in the parameter that identifies which of the two ADC's is being used. Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @briansmith They pass it as a template argument when they instantiate the template: `ADS_1x15<Adafruit_ADS1015>` for example is an instance of the template. The instance of a class template is a class.

Comment: I ended up using a class template for the base class and my descendant class. I had to do a lot of research on exactly how to do that, but it was educational! Thanks, @eerorika  for suggesting that approach.